# How can I eliminate extra space in a stripchart in base R?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, stripchart

I have created a stripchart in R using the code below:

```
oldFaithful <- read.table("http://www.isi-stats.com/isi/data/prelim/OldFaithful1.txt", header = TRUE)
par(bty = "n")              #Turns off plot border
stripchart(oldFaithful,     #Name of the data frame we want to graph
    method = "stack",       #Stack the dots (no overlap)
    pch = 20,               #Use dots instead of squares (plot character)
    at = 0,                 #Aligns dots along axis
    xlim = c(40,100))       #Extends axis to include all data
```

The plot contains a large amount of extra space or whitespace at the top of the graph, as shown below.

[image: Stripchart of oldFaithful data]

Is there a way to eliminate the extra space at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Add the argument `offset=1`, as in

```
stripchart(oldFaithful, offset=1, ...)
```

**Long Answer**

You really have to dig into the code of `stripchart` to figure this one out!

When you set a `ylim` by calling `stripchart(oldFaithful, ylim=c(p,q))` or when you let `stripchart` use its defaults, it does in fact set the `ylim` when it creates the empty plotting area.

However, it then has to plot the points on that empty plotting area. When it does so, the y-values for the points at one x-value are specified as `(1:n) * offset * csize`.  Here's the catch, `csize` is based on `ylim[2]`, so the smaller you make the upper ylim, the smaller is `csize`, effectively leaving the space at the top of the chart no matter the value of `ylim[2]`.

As a quick aside, notice that you can "mess with" `ylim[1]`.  Try this:

```
stripchart(oldFaithful, ylim=c(2,10), pch=20, method="stack")
```

OK, back to solving your problem. There is a second reason that there is space at the top of the plot, and that second reason is `offset`.  By default, `offset=1/3` which (like `csize`) is "shrinking" down the height of the y-values of the points being plotted. You can negate this behavior be setting `offset` closer or equal to one, as in `offset=0.9`.

Comment: What is csize? Can it be adjusted?

Comment: In short, no.  You can use `getAnywhere(stripchart.default)` if you want to dig into the code. You'll find that `csize <- cex * yinch(par("cin")[2L])`